# AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, apparmor

I am using Ubuntu Linux. I was trying to deploy a Rails app using Docker. When I run $ sudo make run is shows this Error.

ERROR: Service 'ranger' failed to build: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: running `/sbin/apparmor_parser apparmor_parser -Kr /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default749298809` failed with output: apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "docker-default".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?

error: exit status 243
Makefile:55: recipe for target 'dependencies' failed
make: *** [dependencies] Error 1

Need help to overcome this situation.